# pandas delete row with multiple string condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete row which are not enough represented. 
I got a data frame df:

```
classif ID    img
Cat     50    matrix(100,100)
Cat     12    matrix(100,100)
Circle  36    matrix(100,100)
Tree    23    matrix(100,100)
...
```

I can see how many *Area* or *Circle* i have with `time=df.classif.value_counts()`

I want to find the **classif** which are present at least 50 times.

`uu= df[df.classif.isin(time.index[time.values > 50])].classif.value_counts()`

it returns me a data frame DF2 like that:

```
Index classif
cat   51
tree  150
```

So it means I have 51 rows with cat and 150 row with tree in my data frame df.

Now I want to select from DF2 those index and keep in DF only the lines where *classif* is in DF2 index.

I have done this but it doesn't work:

```
for enough in uu.index.tolist():
    h=df.loc[df.classif != enough]
```

I think question has been already answered but I can make a code who works... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution!

1/ add index to df

`df=df.set_index("classif",drop=False)`

2/ use drop

`high_defect=df.drop(uu.index.tolist())`